# Pre-image of a closed set is closed implies function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let function $f$ be defined from $D \to \mathbb{R}$, $D \subset R$ closed. If the preimage of every closed set $A$ is closed, then $f$ is continuous.

I was trying to use the standard definition of continuity, so take arbitrary $x_0 \in D$ and show that $\forall \frac 1 m, \exists \frac 1 n. |x - x_0| < \frac 1 n \implies |f(x) - f(x_0) | < \frac 1 m$.

Take arbitrary $\frac 1 m$. Let $A$ be the closed set ranging from $[f(x_0 - \frac 1 m), f(x_0 + \frac 1 m)]$ and hence the closed preimage $f^{-1}(A)$ contains $x_0$ as well and also ranges over $[x_0 - \frac 1 m, x_0 + \frac 1 m]$.

Then we know that any $x \in f^{-1}(A)$ satisfies $|x - x_0| < \frac 1 m$ and it also follows that $f(x) \in A$ by definition of preimage, so $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \frac 1 m$, showing convergence.

Does this proof work?

Comment: This fails for $x^2$ and $0$, the preimage needn't contain $x_0 = 0$ in this case. Consider that: $f^{-1} (A^c) = f^{-1} (A)^c$, where $c$ is the complement, so you can work with open sets.

Comment: @GabrielC.Barbosa thank you, so I think I should work towards showing for every open set, its preimage is also open